# Method returning alternative data structures based on execution result

Tags: java, oop

Say I have a function that looks at a file and returns two results: recognized and unrecognized. When it returns the recognized result, I want the result to also contain a message but when it is unrecognized, no message is necessary.

```
public Result checkFile(File file) {
    ...
}
```

There are two ways I can think of to accomplish this...

Have the `Result` class like so:

```
class Result {

    private Type type;
    private String message;

    enum Type { 
        RECOGNIZED, UNRECOGNIZED
    }

}
```

Or do it like so:

```
class Result {
}

class Unrecognized extends Result {
}

class Recognized extends Result {
    private String message;
}
```

I'm inclined to use the second method, even though I'd have to check the result using `instanceof` and I've read that `instanceof` should be avoided whenever possible, but doing this avoids having a null message when the result is unrecognized. For this example a null message wouldn't be much of an issue, but what if there is a lot more data associated with a recognized result? It seems like worse practice to me to instantiate a class that could have all null fields.

What is the best practice to handle this situation? Is there some standard method or pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Two classes might be overkill, because of it being one and the same class of object. Also an `enum` with two values which merely reassemble `true` and `false` is not required. One `class Result` should suffice and this would also remove the demand for a common `interface`. I'd be all for "no complexity beyond necessary" ...

```
class RecognitionResult {

    private String message = "default message";
    private boolean recognized = false;

    public Result() {}

    public Result(boolean value) {
        this.setRecognised(value);
    }

    public boolean setRecognised(boolean value) {
        this.recognized = value;
    }

    public boolean setMessage(@NonNull String value) {
        this.message = value;
    }

    public boolean getRecognised() {
        return this.recognized;
    }

    @Nullable
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.recognized ? this.message : null;
    }
}
```

then one can simply do:

```
return new RecognitionResult(true);
```

an `interface` for asynchronous callbacks might look alike this:

```
interface Recognition {
    void OnComplete(RecognitionResult result);
}
```

or if you really want to optimize:

```
interface Recognition {
    void OnSuccess(RecognitionResult result);
    void OnFailure(RecognitionException e);
}
```

Comment: If you go this route you should add the @nullable annotation.

Comment: @BakonJarser added annotations; but the `@NonNull` makes more sense.

Comment: But what if a recognized `Result` has a lot more data associated than just `message`? Would it not be a waste of resources/memory to instantiate an unrecognized `Result` and have all the fields contain a default value or null when I would not even need to consider them?

Comment: @user7028506 this is a class according to your specification. if you want to save resources (in times where phones have 2-4GB of RAM), just return a `boolean` value... strings should not be hard-coded, in general.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there's no 'correct' design here - it's going to be a matter of opinion which way you go. However my view is that the modern trend in OOD is to minimise the use of extension and to use delegation and implementation of interfaces wherever possible.

As a general rule, whenever you think of using `instanceof`, reconsider your design.

This would be my suggestion:

```
interface Result {
    boolean isRecognised();
    String getMessage();
}

class RecognisedResult implements Result {
    private final String message;

    public boolean isRecognised() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}

class UnrecognisedResult implements Result {
    public boolean isRecognised() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No message for unrecognised results");
    }
}
```

Comment: and how about when returning these independent classes, which only implement a common `interface`? this might not suit the expected method signature... and therefore it would be a return value of generic type `<T>`... maybe followed by some `instanceof`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler sorry I don't understand your comment. the function would return a `Result` no need for generics or `instanceof`

Comment: there is no `Result`, there's only `RecognisedResult` and `UnrecognisedResult`, which are difficult to push trough an `interface`, unless they'd extend the same base class.

Comment: @MartinZeitler sorry that doesn't make any sense at all. I don't know what 'push through an interface' means. I've demonstrated how they can implement a common interface which would be the return type of your method.

Comment: an `interface` expects **one** data-type and a "result" often is being returned through the implementation of such an interface. just think it makes no sense to create two different kinds of result.

Comment: What does 'an interface expects one data-type' mean? I have no idea what you mean by an interface expecting something.

Comment: an `interface` by itself is the definition, a) which methods need to be implemented and b) which parameters are being expected. this is important for asynchronous callbacks... and two types of result is complexity not required, especially because this does not make anything easier. and bad interface design distributes itself across all classes, which implement it (that complexity is literally being multiplicated).

Comment: Let me ask again. What does 'an interface expects one data-type' mean?

Comment: it means that having two types of result would require two different interface methods. the second interface I've came up with also has two methods, but one expects an exception. classes may not only implement interface methods, but become part of an interface description (as the name "result" already hints for).

Comment: @MartinZeitler I'm sorry but that's completely wrong. The two 'types' of results implement the same interface called `Result`. Honestly I suspect we're not on the same page here so I'm not sure there's a lot of point continuing this discussion. Good luck.

Comment: even if both classes implement `Result`, you may end up with `instanceof`... it's far more common to return result & error in two separate methods, then it's clear already what it is. it may be a matter of taste, but it's convenient alike this.

Comment: @MartinZeitler You don’t need an `instanceOf` check, you’ll simply call the `isRecognised` method on the `Result` type. It appears you don’t understand how type inheritance works.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at the way Retrofit implement your concept of "recognised" and "message" 
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html. it is similar to your first method.

what they did is to have a class called Response, containing a method called isSuccessful(), and a method called body() containing the payload if it's successful (or null if it is unsuccessful.

you can try some thing like the following

```
class Result {

    private Type type;
    private String message;

    public bool isSuccessful(){
            return type == RECOGNIZED;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
            return message; //null if unrecognized.
    }

    enum Type { 
        RECOGNIZED, UNRECOGNIZED
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The functional way to do this would be to use an `Either` type, which doesn’t come with the JDK, but is available in [vavr](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/1.0.0-alpha-2) library. Based on your comments on this thread, it appears you don’t clearly understand how type inheritance works. In that case, a functional solution may be overkill, and I’d suggest going with @sprinter’s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55858721/839733).